# Advantage of `make_unique` over plain constructor?

Tags: c++

I am wondering whether there is any advantage in declaring `Box` with a smart pointer (as `Box3` in the code below) over the (for me more classical) declaration by calling the constructor (as `Box2` in the code below) or if the difference between these two constructions  essentially a matter of subjective preferences.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Box{
    private:
        double length;
        double width;
        double height;
    public:
        Box(double lengthValue, double widthValue, double heightValue); 
        double volume() const;      
};
Box::Box(double lValue, double wValue, double hValue):
    length {lValue}, width {wValue}, height {hValue} {
}
double Box::volume() const {
    return length * width * height;
}
int main() {    
    Box Box2 {1.5,2.5,3.5};
    std::cout << Box2.volume() << std::endl;    
    auto Box3 = std::make_unique<Box>(1.5,2.5,3.5);
    std::cout << Box3->volume() << std::endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it's not that using a pointer has "advantages" over not using a pointer. Sometimes a pointer is *required*. Sometimes dynamic memory allocation is *required*. If you don't need them, don't use them "just because".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dynamic allocation is an expensive operation relative to other basic operations in C++, so you should avoid it where it's not required.

That is, one big difference is that the dynamic allocation is slow.

Another difference is what you can do with it. The dynamically allocated instance can be made to persist after the block where it was crated, by moving ownership. In contrast, the directly declared variable ceases to exist when execution leaves the block.

Answer (score 0):

**Box2 - allocated on the stack**

*Advantages*

- allocation is cheap (just decrement the stack pointer)

*Disadvatages*

- the associated `Box` for Box2 must be created when it is declared
- Stack memory is limited and your program will probably crash if you run out
- You cannot move `Box2` to another object without copying (or moving) all the data members individually.

**Box3 - allocated on the heap**

*Advantages*

- you can catch out of memory conditions `catch (std::bad_alloc) and potentially deal with them without crashing
- you can create your object `Box` well after you declare `Box3`
- you can move your Box object without having to copy (or move) all the individual data members.

*Disadvatages*

- Box3 is allocated on the heap which is a slow operation.

Comment: There are some eyebrow-raising moments in this answer. _"Box2 can never be a null" placed firmly under "disadva[n]tages"_? Really? And use of "stack"/"heap". What makes you think you can only "move" from dynamically-allocated objects? etc

Comment: #Lightness Races in Orbit -I have tried editing the answer to address your concerns. Please feel free to fix anything that you think needs fixing.

Comment: Better I suppose but you'd still be better off avoiding this old and inaccurate "on the stack"/"on the heap" terminology, and instead talk about allocation semantics and storage duration.

Answer (score -1):

No advantages in provided code, only disadvantages.